# Use vue-youtube only in a single SFC file

Tags: vue.js

I'm using [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-youtube) and in the documentation it says that we have to import it in `main.js`

```js
import VueYoutube from 'vue-youtube'
Vue.use(VueYoutube)
```

How to import it in some Vue files only? So that my project won't have to import this package if it's not used in a certain pages. I have tried

```html
<template>
   <youtube :video-id="videoId" ref="youtube"></youtube>
</template>

<script>
import { YouTube } from 'vue-youtube'
export default {
  components: { YouTube }
}
</script>
```

or

```html
<template>
   <youtube :video-id="videoId" ref="youtube"></youtube>
</template>

<script>
import { YouTube } from 'VueYoutube'
export default {
  components: { YouTube }
}
</script>
```

but it still doesn't work. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably import it in `main.js` and it will be tree-shaken at some point by Webpack.

But if you want to use it in a single file only nonetheless, you can follow this github thread answer: https://github.com/anteriovieira/vue-youtube/issues/33#issuecomment-547745879

```html
<template>
   <youtube :video-id="videoId" ref="youtube"></youtube>
</template>

<script>
import { Youtube } from 'vue-youtube'

export default {
  components: {
    Youtube,
  }
}
</script>
```

And it should work properly then !